# listening to click or double click even from other windows8 apps in my app?

Tags: html, windows-8, winjs

I want to create an app which just listen to the double click event from every other windows app where its possible and then open up and dialogue box showing the text selected with double click event from those other apps.

i.e I want to be able to listen any double click event outside of my html5 + winJSapp and then process the selected text in my app.

Comment: This would not be possible unless you controlled the code in the other applications windows as well. Even then you would likely run into cross-domain issues that would need to be resolved.

Comment: You could do this in Win32 land using something called a CBT hook. This capability is explictly removed from Win8 apps, as these hooks usually did more harm than good, and were a good way to corrupt other processes.

Answer (score 0):

Every app in Windows 8 is in its own sandbox and therefore cannot interact with other apps the way you are wanting.

Answer (score 0):

Playing in the sandbox

> First up is sandboxing. Metro-style apps are all sandboxed: by
>   default, each app can only read from and write to its own private
>   storage area. If the app needs to do anything more than this—access
>   the Pictures library, say, or connect to the network as either a
>   client or a server—it must explicitly indicate that it needs these
>   extra capabilities in something called a manifest. This prevents apps
>   from being able to read each other's files, documents that you haven't
>   explicitly granted them permission to read, and so on. This serves two
>   purposes; it helps safeguard user privacy, instilling greater
>   confidence in apps downloaded from the store, and it also reduces the
>   impact of security flaws in those apps.